# How can I run my API on an image?

Tags: import, image, wolfram-cloud

I've built an API that takes a url of an image as an argument. Using `Import[]` I can easily call my API on any url and get the results... but ***I need to run it on an image created within my notebook***.

What is the easiest (and free if possible) way to automatically upload my images and get back urls to feed into my API? I have roughly 100 jpeg images, each is a less than one mB.

Surely there is an easy way to do this, I mean with all this Wolfram-Cloud stuff now in circulation!

Comment: Why not just overload the API definition so it takes a file path as well as a url as a parameter?  Assuming of course that your images are already local.

Comment: Because it is a client requirement to have locals trigger "Bad Request" (HTTP status code 400).

Comment: Can you elaborate the scenario a bit more?  Im having trouble understanding.

Comment: Would `uri = CloudExport[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "JPEG"]`suffice? Inside the cloud object there is a URI to the image.

Comment: That works thanks @Pickett

Comment: @Pickett please consider posting a scheme in answer, or do you think it should be closed for some reason?

Comment: @Kuba I think it can stay open, I posted an answer now.

Comment: @Pickett Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images can be uploaded to Wolfram Cloud with built-in functions. Example:

```
uri = CloudExport[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "JPEG"]
```

`uri` is an expression that contains the URI.